# How can I control the name of an XML element when using custom serialization in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, serialization

I'm working with an externally developed XSD that I need to conform to, where a field `Engine` can be one of two types: `Electric` or `Combustion`. Both are derived from super-class `Engine`.

There are multiple ways to have the `XmlSerializer` in C# handle this, but all are seemingly associated with the same side-effect: default serialization naming conventions are tossed out the window when using a custom serializer-apporach. I want to mimic the default behaviour for the remaining fields of the class `Vehicle`.

Consider the following:

```cs
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace DMV
{
    public class Vehicle : IXmlSerializable
    {
        public Engine Engine { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Manufacturer")]
        public Company Manufacturer { get; set; }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            XmlSerializer engineSerializer = new XmlSerializer(Engine.GetType());
            engineSerializer.Serialize(writer, Engine);
            
            XmlSerializer manufacturerSerializer = new XmlSerializer(Manufacturer.GetType());
            manufacturerSerializer.Serialize(writer, Manufacturer);
        }
    }

    public abstract class Engine { }

    public class Electric : Engine
    {
        public int Poles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Combustion : Engine
    {
        public int CC { get; set; }
    }

    public class Company 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I try to run this using following serialization code:

```cs
Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
vehicle.Engine = new Electric();
vehicle.Manufacturer = new Company();

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Vehicle));
TextWriter writer = new StringWriter();
serializer.Serialize(writer, vehicle);

Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
writer.Close();
```

The result is the following dissapointing pile of caballus faeces:

```xml
<Vehicle>
  <Electric>
    <Poles>0</Poles>
  </Electric>
  <Company/>
</Vehicle>
```

(Yes, the `Engine` field is serialized properly, but `Company` not so much.)

If I had used the default (built-in) serialization I would've gotten the following (desired!) output:

```xml
<Vehicle>
  <Manufacturer />
</Vehicle>
```

How can I both serialize the derived classes `Electric` or `Combustion`, while retaining the default naming convention for field `Manufacturer` (of type `Company`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the custom serializer by doing this:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [XmlElement(typeof(Electric), ElementName = "Electric")]
    [XmlElement(typeof(Combustion), ElementName = "Combustion")]
    public Engine Engine { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Manufacturer")]
    public Company Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a [specific constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlSerializer__ctor_System_Type_System_Type___) for `XmlSerializer` that accepts an array of 'other types' to handle your derived classes, rather than implementing `IXmlSerializable` and doing the serialization manually.  The serializer will now handle your derived classes, but also pick up your other attributes (such as `XmlElement`) the way you want:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
            vehicle.Engine = new Electric();
            vehicle.Manufacturer = new Company();

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Vehicle), new Type[] { typeof(Combustion), typeof(Electric)});
            TextWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            serializer.Serialize(writer, vehicle);

            Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

    public class Vehicle
    {
        public Engine Engine { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Manufacturer")]
        public Company Manufacturer { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Engine { }

    public class Electric : Engine
    {
        public int Poles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Combustion : Engine
    {
        public int CC { get; set; }
    }

    public class Company
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Vehicle xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Engine xsi:type="Electric">
    <Poles>0</Poles>
  </Engine>
  <Manufacturer />
</Vehicle>
```

Unlike the accepted answer, this approach has the advantage of not linking the base class to all possible derived classes. (Any time you add a new derived type in that approach, you have to come back and edit the base type.) While this example has `Program.Main()` hard-coding the array of derived types, you could just as easily use Reflection to build that array, making it even easier to add new derived types.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it.

1. Add `XmlRoot` attribute to `Company` class definition:

   ```
    [XmlRoot("Manufacturer")]
    public class Company
   ```
2. Add `XmlRootAttribute` to `XmlSerializer` constructor.

   ```
    manufacturerSerializer = new XmlSerializer(Manufacturer.GetType(),
        new XmlRootAttribute("Manufacturer"));
   ```

   Pay attention to this: [Dynamically Generated Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netcore-3.1#dynamically-generated-assemblies).

Comment: Thanks for your input Alexander. I should've added in my description that `Company` is being used in other contexts in the XML, like `RentalCompany` and thus can't be bound to a specific name at the class level.